# jbimages plugin for uploading image 404 not found

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, razor

I have jbimages plugin for uploading image in my asp.net project and after press upload image button it take a long time. I got this error and I'm sure the path is exist.

> Most likely causes:
>   The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
>   The URL contains a typographical error.
>   A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.
>
> Things you can try: Create the content on the Web server. Review the
>   browser URL. Check the failed request tracing log and see which module
>   is calling SetStatus. For more information, click here.
>
> Detailed Error Information: Module       IIS Web Core Notification
>   MapRequestHandler Handler    StaticFile Error Code       0x80070002
>   Requested URL
>   ~tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english
>   Physical Path
>   ~\tinymce\js\tinymce\plugins\jbimages\ci\index.php\upload\english
>   Logon Method     Anonymous Logon User    Anonymous Request Tracing
>   Directory    ~\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\COMPARING.UI.WEB(2)
>
> More Information: This error means that the file or directory does not
>   exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request
>   again. View more information »